# Redux Toolkit Queries or/and memoized selectors?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

in my rtkq project, i call as an example, useGetNotesQuery in other pages and components, since i provide tags, rtkq will check the cache before making another api call, to which if the cache has changed, it will load from the cache without an api call, and if it hasnt changed, then load the cache. Is there then any point to also use memoized selectors then if rtkq already watches and has its own cache system?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, tags have nothing to do with the decision of making another api call when data is requested. Tags are about making new api calls (or removing cache entries) after you trigger a mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking about is effectively for an apples and oranges comparison. Redux-toolkit Query (RTKQ) is a tool that serves a completely different use case than what selector functions are used for.

| Redux-Toolkit Query | State selector functions |
| --- | --- |
| - Is a query state management tool. - Is an abstraction built over Redux-Toolkit, it manages API requests, caches responses, invalidates cached responses, manages the initialized/loading/fetching states. - [Uses selector functions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#select). "React Hooks users will most likely never need to use these directly, as the hooks automatically use these selectors as needed." In other words, the `useGetNotesQuery` hook already uses a memoized selector internally. The RTKQ hooks abstract the micromanagement of the initiating and caching of data from your APIs. | Selector functions are simply functions that select a specific slice, or chunk, of state in a Redux store. Some selector functions memoize their result value based on their inputs. |

> Is there then any point to also use memoized selectors then if rtkq
> already watches and has its own cache system?

I'm generally inclined to say "no", use memoized selectors where it makes sense, i.e. when you are selecting computed or derived state from the redux store composed from your state slices. It doesn't make much sense to try to use selectors to select the query state that the app's api slices manage, use the query hooks.

Comment: so for example, in this code:   
  const { note } = useGetNotesQuery("notesList", {
    selectFromResult: ({ data }) => ({
      note: data?.entities[id],
    }),
  });

  const { users } = useGetUsersQuery("usersList", {
    selectFromResult: ({ data }) => ({
      users: data?.ids.map((id) => data?.entities[id]),
    }),
  }); im extracting a specific part from the respective queries, and still rtkq will check its cache to load that first, from what youve said this sounds like it could also be done via memoized selectors, but its redudant as rtkq is already doing that?

Comment: so why does rtkq offer memoized selectors then?

Comment: @CodeOnTheWall RTKQ is built on top of RTK, which provides the selectors. RTKQ uses the selectors internally when building the generated hooks. If you inspect the [example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#example-1) in the doc I linked in answer you can see that they use a selector and memoize it, but they also manually start the subscription (and unsubscription). If you needed the polling or conditional skip logic, etc... all this would also need to be manually implemented in userland.

Comment: @CodeOnTheWall All this is abstracted in the query hooks for you. OFC, if you are still using Class components for some reason, it's an escape hatch since you'd need to do all this because you couldn't use hooks.

Comment: I came back to review you answers for the same project as im testing things right now and never realized I didn't thank you for your time and great explanation! It really helped me reduce code in my project and have a better understanding. Thank you very much Drew!

Comment: @CodeOnTheWall No worries, glad to help. Typically votes are sufficient enough to indicate "thanks", but I always appreciate the extra thoughts and kind words. We live in a society, you know. Cheers and good luck!